# how to rotate a view along x axis

Tags: android-animation

I want to rotate a view along its x axis.I tried to do the following:

```
AnimationSet anim=new AnimationSet(true);
RotateAnimation rotate=new      RotateAnimation(0.0f,-10.0f,RotateAnimation.ABSOLUTE,0.5f,RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
rotate.setFillAfter(true);
rotate.setDuration(5000);
rotate.setRepeatCount(0);
anim.addAnimation(rotate);
View relatv1=(View)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
relatv1.setAnimation(anim);
```

but i instead the view rotates along its y axis.How can i accomplish x axis rotation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an ObjectAnimator like this:

```
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotationX", 0.0f, 360f);
    animation.setDuration(5000);
    animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ObjectAnimator` class does the rotation along the axis for the view that is passed as an argument to `ofFloat` method.

If you want to rotate the view only once don't set any repeat count.

The [answer from "its-tomweber"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215076/how-to-rotate-a-view-along-x-axis/27965619#27965619) is working perfectly.